# How can I execute multiple ADF pipelines based on some conditions but without nesting the if activities?

Tags: azure-data-factory

My requirement is to loop over same set of files using multiple pipelines

e.g.

1. pipeline 1 consumes file 1 and then a certain output is generated
2. now pipeline 2 has to be triggered based on output of pipeline 1 else we should skip the run
3. If pipeline 2 runs then pipeline 3 has to be triggered based on output of pipeline 2 else we should skip the run

Is there any way to do this in ADF without nesting if-else  ?

Comment: Is the output to Blob storage? If so, you could create BlobCreated triggers for the subsequent pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through multiple pipelines using combination of **"Execute Pipeline activity"** and **"If Activity"**. The [Execute Pipeline activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-execute-pipeline-activity) allows a Data Factory pipeline to invoke another pipeline. For false condition execute a different pipeline. Optionally if the child pipeline flow add **"Execute Pipeline activity"** refering the previous caller!

`Caution: can get into a dangerous loop if right conditions are not configured.`

[image]

[image]